# Python Flask - No module named 'wtforms.csrf'

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

After installing flask-wtf with pip, creating the form below

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo


def Register(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[Datarequired(), Length(min = 2, max= 20)])
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[Datarequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[Datarequired(), Length(min = 6, max= 100)])
    confirm_password = PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators=[Datarequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField("Sign Up")
```

and running python app.py

i get the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from forms import Registration, Login
  File "D:\python\sublime\flaskdbapp\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
  File "C:\Users\laravel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf-0.14.2-py3.7.egg\flask_wtf\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .csrf import CSRFProtect, CsrfProtect
  File "C:\Users\laravel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf-0.14.2-py3.7.egg\flask_wtf\csrf.py", line 12, in <module>
    from wtforms.csrf.core import CSRF
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.csrf'
```

Cant find solution, kindly assist

Comment: Try updating your flask_wtf by using 
pip install --user --upgrade flask-wtf

Comment: Done, still not working, response is requirements already satisfied

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution for me was to reinstall WTForms:

```
pip install WTForms --upgrade
```

I think the cause for me was installing flask-wysiwyg which downgraded flask-wtf to 0.9.4. As flask-security requires flask-wtf >=0.13.1, I upgraded flask-wtf again straight awaybut then this issue manifested.